# ORA 00904 error in a procedure without a "SELECT" statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, ora-00904

I have a simple procedure that should delete all rows with "CREATEDATE" earlier than the given input parameter "p_date".
For some reason I keep getting `"ORA-00904: "P_DATE": invalid identifier":`

```
PROCEDURE     DELETE_TABLE (p_date date) IS
begin
   delete from db.table
   where CREATEDATE<=p_date;
   commit;
end ;
```

Comment: Is that exactly how the procedure is defined? The parameter isn't quoted (`"p_date" date`) it the declaration? Is it reportiing the error against the declaration or the `where` clause? Is it a compilation error or a runtime error - if the latter, how are you calling it?

Comment: @Alex Poole It was a compilation error caused by the fact that I neglected the "create or replace" statement. Therefore the problem was solved. Thank you for your answer